# How to access contents of a keyless array to object conversion?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I'm experimenting with OOP and PHP.

I don't know why I would ever need to do something like this but I'm wondering how it would be done and cant find it online.

```
class Example{

public $a = 'aye';
public $b = 'bee';
public $c = 'see';

public function how(){
    return (object)array(
                         $this->a,
                         $this->b,
                         $this->c
                        );
    }    
}

$example = new Example;
$how = $example->how(); 
echo $how->1; //I thought would print bee
```

I'm aware that giving the **array keys** would let me do

```
echo $how->beekey //which would give me beekey's value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically not possible, as explained in this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60379); numeric object properties are kind of a gray area in PHP.

However, you can cast the object back to an array and reference the value:

```
$arr = (array)$how;
echo $arr[1];
```

Or, use as a one-liner:

```
echo current(array_slice((array)$how, 1, 1));
```

The best advice I could give you is to not turn it into an object in the first place:

```
public function how()
{
    return array(
        $this->a,
        $this->b,
        $this->c
    );
}
```

And then just reference it as `$how[1]`.

Btw, `$how->{1}` [used to work](http://3v4l.org/7Amt1) in PHP 4 :)

Comment: thanks for the response. Is it common practice to return arrays in OOP?

Comment: @chris Well, no; but turning arrays into anonymous objects for the sake of doing "OO" is usually not done. You can use an [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/arrayobject) though.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **a loop?**

```
foreach($how as $value)
{
    echo $value .'<br>'; //this print your values: aye<br>bee<br>see
}
```

Comment: You don't need the counter for `foreach` loop. Just echo the `$value`.

Comment: There's still an `$i++` in your loop. Although this approach works it doesn't let the developer to access elements directly. I thought that $how->{1} might save the day but it returns empty value, sadly.

Comment: It did indeed, yes. Stats show, though, that 97% of the sites powered by PHP are running version 5 and up.